# Extract and convert Datetime field from JSON in SNOWFALKE

Tags: json, datetime, parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am receiving a Datetime field in my JSON which looks like the below screenshot
where first 4 characters are year, next two characters are month, next two characters are date, next two characters are hour, next two characters are minutes and last two characters are seconds.

[image]

I extracted the date successfully and tried to convert using **to_timestamp** function in **SNOWFLAKE** but returns me the result like
**"2606-08-31 03:17:04.416"**

code that I am working with to convert into Timestamp

```
select distinct to_timestamp(a.value) within group(order by to_timestamp(a.value)) from orders a
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default format for conversion](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-timestamp-input-format) is `AUTO`, which will attempt to guess.  It appears as though it is guessing incorrectly.

To specify a format, add a second parameter to your call to `to_timestamp` that is a string of the format. [Here are the docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html).

```
to_timestamp(a.value, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

Comment: Hi,  I tried doing it and it throws the below error
SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 26 too many arguments for function [TO_TIMESTAMP(LF.VALUE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')] expected 1, got 2

Comment: Sounds like it MIGHT be considering `a.value` to be a numeric value rather than a string, which will have a different behavior for the function. Try to first cast `a.value` to a string via `::string`, and then provide the format string with it.

Comment: it's best to always cast your `VARIANT` data, as it's is nether `NUMBER` or `STRING` and if that field can hold values that are not the type of this field in this object is hold, then that will fail the cast, in which case you will need to use the `TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP` to avoid the failure, this can happen even if you have a filter than means only valid data will reacht eh cast, as the CAST happen before the WHERE sometimes.